# Occasionally on refreshing the page the hidden content by jQuery will appear for few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, refresh

I have created a jQuery Dialog for storing a hidden image, which will only be triggered by clicking a link. Some of the codes are as followed:

```
<div id="dialogdialog" style="background-color: white;">
            <div>
                 <div style="clear: right">
                 <a href="#" class="closeDialogButton">
                     <div id="fitClose" class='sprite x' style="float:right;"></div></a>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="fitLogoBlack" class='sprite black-logo'></div>
                <br/><br/>
                <img id="fitTitle" src="img/fitguide_title.jpg">
                <img id="fitLogoBlue" src="img/blue.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/topbanner01.jpg">
                <br/>
                <img src="img/slim02.jpg">
            </div>


        </div>



<a class="fit-guide" href="#fit-guide" target="_self" rel="nofollow" id="fitguidePic">Fit Guide</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialogdialog").dialog({
            width: 900,
            border: 0,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizeable: false,
            dialogClass:"myClass"

        });
        $("#fitguidePic").on("click", function() {
            $("#dialogdialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });

    $('.closeDialogButton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialogdialog').dialog('close');
    })
    </script>
```

And the codes are working, the image can be hidden until I clicked on the link, however, occasionally when I refresh my page, I will see the hidden content appeared on the page for few seconds, but after the whole page is fully loaded, it will be hidden again. But this situation does not happened for every refresh.

I have no idea what this problem is caused. How can I stop the image popping up when refreshing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#dialogdialog {
    display: none;
}
```

Because displaying of the page in the browser doesn't wait for Javascript to be fully loaded the dialog is sometimes visible, because it is visible by default. jQuery will later 'overwrite' this initial setting by attaching CSS directly to the element.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I stop the image popping up when refreshing?

By using vanilla js (raw js). Why ?

> I have no idea what this problem is caused.

This is because jQuery (if properly set) is loaded only after the whole document has loaded. So when you refresh the image appear first and then the code hidding it is loaded after that. Anytime there is a delay and the loading is slow, you will see the picture before it is hidden if using jQuery.

Alt solution : you can load jQuery without waiting for the document to fully load but your code might break and this is generally a really bad idea. jQuery works only on whole documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: none; on #dialogdialog
```